# My SE Reputation log display +10 but it should be +5 because my reputation went up only 5 points... Why?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-history

I just noticed that my reputation log displays that I have earned +10 reputation but everywhere else including the number in my actual reputation went up only by 5.

How come?

This is an image of my profile reputation part:

[image]

Comment: You would have gotten an upvote on a question that was later reversed. Probably, on the "How to ping ..." question, as it now shows +5 and not +10

Answer (score 4):

You also earned another +5 on that question on December 17th. The system added the two together and is showing you the *total* recent change from that post.

Comment: I never experienced this, though. It always shows the most recent rep changes, not sum of changes as it always appeared.

Comment: No one really knows exactly how it determines recent events. It definitely seems random. I think it tries to choose the events you'd be more interested in or something, because it doesn't appear to follow any standard for timeframes.